# Ho to give a dynamic Class or ID to an element based on the current page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my MVC project I need to give a Class or an ID to the Body tag, but I can't because **my Body is on the Layout page.**

How can I give an ID or a Class to the Body tag or to a DIV tag instead **based on the View name**?

Any advises?

Comment: You could pass a value indicating the item to highlight using a `ViewBag` property or you could use javascript to read the current request and highlight the appropriate item

Comment: agree with Stephen, ViewBag can do the job, I think in the default template the Html Title is set in the same fashion.

Comment: Thanks a lot that did it!

Comment: Nope. you set a value to an arbitrary Property in the viewbag in your controller (or view) like this: "ViewBag.BodyClass = "classToSet" and then in the layout page <body class="@ViewBag.BodyClass">.

I need to point out though that is not an ideal approach. it is best to separate the controller logic from the view logic.

Comment: Not really sure why you have accepted the answer you did - your question title is about highlighting one of your menu items based on the current page, not adding a class to a single element. At the very least its going to involve some javascript (or if not, then a huge number of conditional statements in the view)

Comment: the title doesn't match the question I think. (EDIT: now i've seen the edit :))

Comment: You are right, I didn't explain myself properly, I edited my title. The solution @Massimo Franciosa gave me, solved my issue, I have to give a dynamic ID to the Body tag or to a Div and that did this solution, the next level of highlighting the curent link on the Menu, will be the graphic designer's job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set an arbitrary property into the ViewBag in your controller like this:

```
ViewBag.BodyClass = "classToSet"
```

and then in the layout page

```
<body class="@ViewBag.BodyClass">
```

I need to point out though that is not an ideal approach. it's always best to separate the logic (inside the controller) and the style of the view. an alternative approach is to use the ViewBag with a flag rather than the class itself. for example:

```
ViewBag.ShowAlternativeStyle = true;
```

And then in the view:

```
<body class="@(ViewBag.ShowAlternativeStyle : "classToSet" : "")
```

in this case the class definition is still in the view while the logic (the reason WHY you want a different style) stays inside the controller.

Comment: Can you explain more what is the issue with the first solution? Thank you very much for your good answer!

Comment: it's just a good practice to separate the logic (inside the controllers) and the style (inside the view and the markup). 

Let's assume you want to change the name of the class. this means that you need to change the actual code and not the markup inside the view. doing so everytime will assure you that if you have a problem with styling, you need only to look at the views, without searching every controller looking for a class name. it's also useful for the fact that is not forcing you to recompile the whole site in order to make a slight change of styling.

Comment: But I didn't write it in the Controller! I wrote on the View:@{
    ViewBag.Title = "X YY ZZ";
    ViewBag.BodyClass = "XYYZZ";
} And on the Layout: <body class="@ViewBag.BodyClass"> So do you think it is still not ideal?

Comment: it depends. What's the condition when the different style needs to be in place?

Comment: Based on the dynamic ID the graphic designer will highlight the selected link on the Menu. Is this what you mean?

Comment: in this case is a bit better as long as styling and markup stuff is in the view and logic in the controller :)